# Pass JSON on Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Lets say you have an object

```
public class SomeViewModel
    {
        public SomeViewModel()
        {
            this.SomeData = new List<SomeData>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname{ get; set; }
        public List<SomeData> SomeData { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

And now i want to pass the model as querystring from ASP.NET application to ASP.NET MVC application

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someModelVM);
//how to convert it to querystring ?
Response.Redirect("http://somedomain.com/SomeAction?redirect=" + querystring, true);
```

so after redirect it would bind properly

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeViewModel someViewModel)
{
//do something here
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've choosen the simples solution instead to complicating.

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someModelVM);
 Response.Redirect("http://somedomain.com/SomeAction?redirect=" + json, true);


public ActionResult SomeAction(string json)
    {
        //try to deserialize json
        //security check the json
        //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that browsers have a limit of how much data can be sent over HTTP using the "GET" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [this](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/serialize-object-into-a-query-string-with-reflection/) example to convert Class to "query string"

for example with the class you have, would have to be something like this:

```
Name = My name
Surname = My Surname
SomeData = [
   {
      Name = My SD0Name,
      Value = My SD0Value
   },
   {
      Name = My SD1Name,
      Value = My SD1Value
   }
]

Name=My%20name&Surname=My%20Surname&SomeData[0].Name=My%20SD0Name&SomeData[0].Value=My%20SD0Value&SomeData[1].Name=My%20SD1Name&SomeData[1].Value=My%21SD0Value
```

then you have to concatenate your url with the new text:

```
var someViewModel = new ToQueryString { Name = "My name", ... };
var querystring = someViewModel.ToQueryString();
Response.Redirect("http://somedomain.com/SomeAction?redirect=" + querystring, true);
```

you do not need `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` because the extension is already dealing do this.

**EDIT** for @Matthew comment. If you have a large query string, you can use a tool like this list to zip query string, then contatenate a value:

[c-compress-and-decompress-strings](http://dotnet-snippets.com/dns/c-compress-and-decompress-strings-SID612.aspx)
[compression-decompression-string-with-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343623/138071)

In this case you can use a Json format, already that you send the zip of the text in a variable. But you need change then action that receives this parameter:

```
Response.Redirect("http://somedomain.com/SomeAction?redirectZip=" + jsonStringZip, true);
```

---

Code from [this](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/serialize-object-into-a-query-string-with-reflection/) blog:

```
public static class UrlHelpers
{
    public static string ToQueryString(this object request, string separator = ",")
    {
        if (request == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

        // Get all properties on the object
        var properties = request.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.CanRead)
            .Where(x => x.GetValue(request, null) != null)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(request, null));

        // Get names for all IEnumerable properties (excl. string)
        var propertyNames = properties
            .Where(x => !(x.Value is string) && x.Value is IEnumerable)
            .Select(x => x.Key)
            .ToList();

        // Concat all IEnumerable properties into a comma separated string
        foreach (var key in propertyNames)
        {
            var valueType = properties[key].GetType();
            var valueElemType = valueType.IsGenericType
                                    ? valueType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                                    : valueType.GetElementType();
            if (valueElemType.IsPrimitive || valueElemType == typeof (string))
            {
                var enumerable = properties[key] as IEnumerable;
                properties[key] = string.Join(separator, enumerable.Cast<object>());
            }
        }

        // Concat all key/value pairs into a string separated by ampersand
        return string.Join("&", properties
            .Select(x => string.Concat(
                Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Key), "=",
                Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Value.ToString()))));
    }
}
```

Comment: You answer is the most detailed but the provided converter doesn't work with complex types, still i'll upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: I think what you need is another question, "How to convert an `Object` to `QueryString`?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someModelVM);
Response.Redirect("http://somedomain.com/SomeAction?redirect=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(json), true);
```

This uses the [`UrlEncode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) to encode your JSON to be part of the URL as querystring

Comment: I need how to get querystring from object, or json. Read the question again.

Comment: @plurby: Of course! Made the change in my answer to use the right variable

Comment: This doesn't work as the Json is just encoded and it's not converted to Param=Value query string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` for this purpose.

Check the documentation from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) and this thread from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12781892/1551730)

Hope it helps.