# How to select a varying token with Regex.Match

Tags: regex, vb.net

So I have a token, and it looks for instance like `asdkl3njkln1mlnmlaskjenr&email=example@gmail.com&asd345d&password=example&asd986asn`

The strings before/after `&email=example@gmail.com&` and `&password=example&` change constantly on each page load.

All I need is for a user to input his username/password to a textbox to check on order status/etc. How would I get the email address and password from the token?

What I tried in VB.NET was:

```
Dim token As String = Regex.Match(htmlPage, "(?\<email=\)+user+(?=\\&\)").Groups(0).Value
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

`htmlpage` being the login page for the site that has the order statuses, which is downloaded in order for `Regex` to get in between those strings, in the token.

Comment: Don't use a regular expression for this. [Use a query string parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (if it is indeed a query string as it looks like).

Comment: @user2864740 is right. Here's an example that will demonstrate how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781829/vb-net-parse-query-string-to-array

Answer (score 0):

While the best answer is using a query parser, I would like to explain the problem with the current regex. The main point is that you over-escaped characters and used a malformed look-behind.

Correct regex will look like this: `(?<=email=)[^&]+(?=&)`

Here is a [sample program](http://goo.gl/rLDnSw) with a fixed working regex:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module VBModule

Sub Main()
    Dim htmlPage As String = "asdkl3njkln1mlnmlaskjenr&email=example@gmail.com&asd345d&password=example&asd986asn"
    Dim token As String = Regex.Match(htmlPage, "(?<=email=)[^&]+(?=&)").Value
    Console.WriteLine(token)
End Sub
End Module
```

Output: `example@gmail.com`